# Can methyl halide be used in Wurtz reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, halides

Yields of product(alkanes) are best for 1°(60%) and least for 3°(10%) alkyl halides. Can methyl halides be used in Wurtz reaction? Would it produce a good yield?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methyl Halide if used , as it is primary alkyl halide and also can produce only one product ethane which is symmetrical and therefore the yield should  be very much high .